# How to use dplyr to perform descriptives and a chi-square test within function

Tags: r, dplyr, chi-squared

my question has a similar one  [here][1], but as long dplyr changes the way it does the things, I believe my question is original and could help other people.

First, I'm trying to **Inside a function**, reports descriptive statistics and run some statistical inference tests, such as chi-square.

This syntax works very well:

```
> desc_chi <- function(group_var) {   group_var <- enquo(group_var)   j
> <- dataset %>% 
>     group_by(!!group_var) %>% 
>     summarise(n = n())   print(j) } 
desc_chi(GENDER)
```

But when I add a Chi-square test, it stops and reports an error:

```
desc_chi <- function(group_var) {
  group_var <- enquo(group_var) 
  j <- dataset %>% 
    group_by(!!group_var) %>% 
    summarise(n = n(),
      pvalue=chisq.test(.$LOCATION, .$group_var))
  print(j)
}
```

*Column `pvalue` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 9*

Thanks for all support you always provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
 desc_chi <- function(dataset, group_var) {   
  group_var <- enquo(group_var)   
  dataset %>% 
      group_by(!!group_var) %>% 
      summarise(n = n()) %>% 
      mutate(chisq_pval = chisq.test(n)$p.value)   
 } 


mtcars %>% 
     desc_chi(cyl)


# A tibble: 3 x 3
    cyl     n chisq_pval
   <dbl> <int>      <dbl>
1  4.00    11      0.315
2  6.00     7      0.315
3  8.00    14      0.315
```

Comment: Thanks, @adam-black, I spent all morning trying to get this result and you solved the problem!!!!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Is it possible to change this code to something like chisq.test(variable1, group_var) ? This group_var is defined by a function! Thanks again

Comment: @Luis I don't think I understand. Maybe you can provide an example.

Comment: Using mtcars, chisq.test(mtcars$am, mtcars$gear). That works. Is it possible something like test <- function(x,y) { chisq.test(mtcars$x, mtcars$y) } and run test(am, gear) . Thanks

Comment: Like this? test <- function(x,y) {chisq.test(table(mtcars[[x]], mtcars[[y]]))}
test("am", "gear")

Comment: You simply can use `count(!!group_var)` instead of grouping and summarising.